# How to set up AnyChart Line graph to autoscroll to the last n entries?

Tags: anychart

I want to use AnyChart line graph which would get data from a stream.
I would like to display only the last n entries, with a possibility to manually scroll to the old entries.

I am looking to a sample on AnyChart playground, and I am able to achieve that when I set `scroller.allowRangeChange(true);` and manually move scroller from left to the center.

https://playground.anychart.com/fyF85xTh/1

But how can I set programatically the scroller to display only n last entries? I do not see any methods on `scroller` to set range.

Comment: P.S. Manually moving xScroller slider to a selected position only partially solves my issue, as it shows only relative number of last entries and not absolute n last entries. That means that over time it will display more and more entries depending on number of entries added.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this effect, you can use methods xScroller() and xZoom() as shown below

```
    // set scroller and zoom mode
      chart.xScroller(true);
      zoom = chart.xZoom();
      zoom.setToPointsCount(5, true); 
    });
```

as well as making sure that zoom is refreshed upon new data addition.
Take a look at the sample here: https://playground.anychart.com/t0BmdJo9/5